# How do I set-up grub to show boot-up options for Debian 10 and Windows 10 from separate drives?

Tags: linux, debian, dual-boot, grub

My system has the following drives: a 500GB SSD, a 2TB HDD, and a 32GB Optane card. 
I'm running Debian 10 from a partition on the SSD (sda), and Windows 10 from the HDD+Optane Intel RST RAID drive (sdb).

Currently I switch between Debian and Win10 by pressing F8 on startup or changing the BIOS setup. I know that grub *should* be able to show me all the bootup options though. I have looked into grub-customizer but couldn't figure it out. How can I add the Win10 boot option from the different drive into the grub options?

Comment: If both operating systems use the same boot style (either UEFI or legacy), then using GRUB to present them both in the boot menu should be possible, and if the `os-prober` package is installed, `update-grub` should be detecting Windows 10 automatically. However, if one OS uses native UEFI and the other uses legacy boot methods, pressing F8/using BIOS settings might be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The os-prober never returned anything from the terminal running from root (sudo -i). However, what worked:

I added this entry to the Grub list (using grub-customizer or editing the file /etc/grub/40_custom directly)

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (UEFI)" {
search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Help from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/211339/invalid-efi-file-path-while-booting-windows